# C code to detect if the compiler allows comments to nest

Tags: c

This is an interview Question that i was asked recently:

> Write a C program which when compiled and run, prints out a message
>     indicating whether the compiler that it is compiled with, allows /* */
>     comments to nest

How to go about this ?

Comment: homework? if so, please tag it as so. what have you tried?

Comment: I think there is some problem with my internet connection currently.
so the question got submitted even before i wanted to submit.

Comment: @amit: i am clueless how to go about this one ?

Comment: `int puts();int main(){puts("no");}`, i.e. a **C** compiler does not allow comments to nest.

Comment: Even i know that. but i was asked to write the code to prove that. and y so many down votes? whats the problem with this question

Comment: Perhaps more to the point, I consider assignments/exercises like this **harmful** because they wrongly teach that C is an un[der]specified language where compilers might vary in how they parse/compile programs, and lead to new C programmers jumping through all sorts of obfuscated loops to be "portable" to "C compilers" that don't and can't exist.

Comment: And I didn't downvote. I'm just commenting that the assignment is stupid. I understand if your instructor assigned it you have to do it. The question has been asked before so you should be able to find the answer. Unfortunately the people who voted to close voted "not a real question" rather than "exact duplicate" so the previous question isn't linked.

Comment: Oops, I mean interviewer not instructor. :-) Of course in that case it might mean if you get hired you'll be working among idiots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int noNesting = 0 /* /* */ + 1 // */
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int main(void)
 {
 int temp=0 /* /* */ + 1 // */
;
    //if nesting allowed temp value woud be 0 otherwise it would be 1
if(temp)
{
printf("Nesting not allowed");
}
else
{
printf("Nesting allowed");
}
return 0;
}
```